# How to handle super script in angular material textarea?

Tags: angular-material

I am getting api response it has super script tag. I am showing it in text area and i am not able to handle it. below is the code and screenshot please help

[image]

```
<div class="delete-dialog" style="padding: 10px;">
<form [formGroup]="editForm" id="validate" (ngSubmit)="yes()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Edit Here...</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput formControlName="title" id="Update {{data.type}}"
             cols="50" rows="5" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <span *ngIf="!editForm.valid" class="text-danger">{{errorMsg}}</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try putting the content into the innerHTML of the textarea?

like so:

```
document.getElementById('Update X')innerHTML = stringWithHTMLTags
```